# Is there a name for the function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a group. Suppose $\psi: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ is a group homomorphism. The function $\phi: G \rightarrow (\mathbb{C},+)$ has the property:

$$ \phi(g_1 g_2) = \phi(g_1) + \psi (g_1) \phi(g_2),$$

for $g_1, g_2$ in $G$.

Is there a name for a function with this property? Note that if $\psi (g) = 1$ for all $g \in G$, then $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $\psi : G \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ as defining a representation of the group $G$ on the $1$-dimensional complex vector space $\mathbb{C}$. Then you can call $\phi$ a *[$1$-cocycle](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/1-cocycle_for_a_group_action) on $G$ with coefficients in $\psi$*, or equivalently, a *crossed homomorphism $G \to \mathbb{C}$* (with respect to the representation $\psi : G \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ on $\mathbb{C}$).